# How can I get bitmap using glide in onCreate?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm using **MVVM** model. So what I have to do is first, getting datas containing URLs and others from retrofit.

Second is getting images from URLs and notifying **Viewpager** after first process.
I did the first. but when I try the second process, the error occurred

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on a
>   background thread

I referred this site http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html#background-threads
to use glide on background thread.

I don't have to use **Asynctask** in observe that is my constraint to develop. How can I solve the second process?

```
 detailViewModel.getIndexItem().observe(this, Observer<DetailModel>(){  
                t->

            binding.item = t

            image_list = binding.item.thumbnail_list_320.toString().split("#")
            for(image in image_list) {
                val futureTarget: FutureTarget<Bitmap> = Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(image)
                    .submit(500, 500)

                val bitmap = futureTarget.get()
                bitmaps.add(bitmap).apply {
                    if(this){
                        viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        transitionLayout.visibility=View.GONE                             
                        detailLayout.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Make an _asynchronous_ call to get bitmap which will be completely loaded using _Glide_

Comment: how can I call asynchronous call in observe?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get bitmap on UI Thread, implement as below, You can try

```
detailViewModel.getIndexItem().observe(this, Observer<DetailModel>(){
            t->

        binding.item = t

        image_list = binding.item.thumbnail_list_320.toString().split("#")
        for(image in image_list) {
            Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .override(500, 500)
                .load("image url")
                .into( object: CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        bitmap: Bitmap,
                        transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {
                        // UI Thread
                        Log.e(TAG, "$bitmap")
                        bitmaps.add(bitmap).apply {
                            if(this){
                                viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                transitionLayout.visibility=View.GONE
                                detailLayout.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                    }

                })

        }
    })
```

Comment: is it right code? I've got the error  at "  override fun onResourceReady(bitmap: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?)"

Comment: I using Glide 4.0, can you refer https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html to import.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and elegant in java:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
Glide.with(mContext).load(PHOTOURL).apply(options).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                 bitmap = resource;
                }
            }).into(IMAGEVIEW);
```

with `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'`. Note that, it is asynchronous and takes some time to load bitmap. I hope it helps. Best regards.

Comment: I wrote that code, and I've got error "no type arguments expected for annotation class target"